# assigning new rootViewController to window doesn't remove current from view Hierarchy when debugging view hierarchy using xcode

Tags: ios, instantiation, uiview-hierarchy, rootviewcontroller

old root view controller not removed when assigning new root view controller

i want to reload the app from its beginning ,but i notice that the old root view Controller not removed from view hierarchy

```
private func reset() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
        else { return }
    window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    UIView.transition(with: window!, duration: 2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the subviews and the root view before assigning the new root view controller

```
       for (UIView* subView in self.window.rootViewController.view.subviews) 
      {
          [subView removeFromSuperview];
      }

      [self.window.rootViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This is apparently a know issue in iOS 
You can see the [Detailed Description](https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/251) here